# How to read and identify values from file with format in Java?

Tags: java, file, format

There's a file I want to read with the following format from a file using Java.

```
ID,Name,Gender
1,ABC,F
```

I can read the values from files. However, I don't know how to ascertain value 'F' is Gender, or value 'ABC' is the name.

How do I differentiate those values with the user provided format?

Comment: It looks  like a CSV file.  Can you base your identification on the index of the value?  e.g. index 1 is Name  and 2 is Gender.  What is the format of file you are parsing?

Comment: Split the string on "," and take the 4th or 5th element of the array? - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: it's txt file or csv file

Comment: Have a look at a framework to help you, for example `smooks`

Comment: thanks guy. i will test first using table in which file format is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guy It works when I use table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library like SuperCSV:
https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html
It can extract the headers and extract the data values into objects with fields matching those header names.
It will also handle values containing commas for you.
i.e. if the value of the Name field is "John, Doe" it will treat it as a single value and not split on the containing comma as long as the values are surrounded by "".
And It also supports CellProcessors witch let you define formats for the values of certain colums like Double or Date, so you dont have to manually handle the type conversions.

Comment: @tak3shi The original file is CSV, although this is quite overkill for a simple parse that could just split on commas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first line as header. This is common when using csv, althought there is no general way to tell if a csv contains a header row or not.

```
ID,Name,Gender
1,ABC,F
2,BCE,F
```